# Trim Enabler Safety

Tags: macos, trim, security

I have a quick question. I am a bit anal about what I run on my Mac, tend to use the apple apps (aperture/terminal) rather than alternatives (Picasa/iterm2) because I like to make sure I'm running safe software.

It sounds a bit tinfoil hat, but as a developer I know there is alot of bad code out there.

I have never hacked about with OSX and as a result I have had a seemless experience through the years, with nearly 0 issues.

Trim enabler has brought my SSD back to life performance wise, but i'm a little concerned that it may be interfering with important system kexts and files.

Do you think TE is safe to use / wont corrupt OS X or the system?

Thanks,
John

Comment: I've described in the following question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88230/how-does-trim-enabler-work/94073#94073 how Trim Enabler works and which file it modifies. It won't corrupt your system as it only modifies one specific kernel extension.

Comment: so you think it can be completely trusted, and makes purely benign changes that would not impact the system in any adverse way for performance or stability or integrity?

Comment: Please also add as an answer and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've described in the following question [How does TRIM Enabler work?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88230/how-does-trim-enabler-work/94073#94073) how Trim Enabler works and which file it modifies. It won't corrupt your system as it only modifies one specific kernel extension. -- Chrisii

Answer (score 2):

I've done it by

1. checking is it active or not (Apple logo on the top left > About this Mac > System Report > on the left hand side SATA/STA Express > then check the drive which you want to enable TRIM Support Yes or No "By build in Apple SSD by default is active by Self service by default it's in active)
2. Open Terminal

   sudo trimforce enable

enter password

Then it will ask you are you sure and then Y for Yes
then again it will ask you are you sure to enable this then again Y for yes

After a while MacBook will reboot and check by Step 1 Trim is enable.

Comment: No worries...just trying to help out  :-)  and Welcome to Ask Different.  Gave you an upvote for a good answer...you're on your way!